Hartshorne exercise I.2.7 reduction
How are you supposed to use Hartshorne Ex I.2.7(b) in Ex I.2.6?
The problem is to prove dimension of a quasiprojective variety is the same as dimension of its closure in $\mathbb{P}^n$. The previous exercise is the statement that dimension of a projective variety is Krull dimension of its homogeneous coordinate ring, minus 1. The hint says use it to reduce the problem to the affine case which is Prop 1.10.
I instead have a purely topological reduction to Prop 1.10, using the fact that if $Y \subset X$ and $U$ is an open set of $X$, then $\overline{Y}^X\cap U = \overline{Y\cap U}^U$. I've been using this fact a lot. But I want to know what the hint is thinking of.
